# AdaBoostClassifier with Random Forests for multilabel classification (sklearn)

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest, adaboost, multilabel-classification

I am trying to use AdaBoostClassifier with RandomForestClassifier on a multiclass multilabel problem/

I understand that AdaBoostClassifier supports multilabel output (wrong, it doesn't!), where y is the 'True labels for X'. Where am I going wrong please? Thanks!

Comment: where did you read that adaboostclassifier would support multilabel output? according to http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html the only models that do this are Decision Trees, Random Forests, Nearest Neighbors, Ridge Regression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no multi-label version of AdaBoost and the label should be the shape of samples number. To classify with multi-label data, you can refer some relative paper methods